# Removing a merge commit

Tags: git

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get rid of commit 5581ecb023a9, which was created in the merging process of two branches. What I'm trying to get to is everything in one straight line.

[image]

So far I've tried to do `git rebase -i 5581ecb023a9` following some previous posts, though it doesn't show the actual 5581ecb023a9 commit. I tried `git rebase -i a19ba5850a20` which also doesn't show the 5581ecb023a9 commit.

Any idea on how to get them all into a line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need a linear history (if so why?) or do you just want a flat list of non-merges such as `git log --no-merges` wil show?

Comment: Yup, a linear history. It's because my commits/merges during my earlier git days are really disorganized, and I'm trying to make them look a bit neater. Basically, yes, what `git log --no-merges` shows is what I'm trying to get to.

Comment: Merge commits aren't disorganized; workflows are. If you've shared this repo with others rewriting history to make the graph simpler could get messy fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to rebase against a commit from *before* either side of the merge diverged from their common ancestor - e.g. `git rebse 8fedb6`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the commits in one line *logically*, but by doing so you *rewrite history*.

This means that the commits will have different ids (SHA1 checksums) since each revision in git includes their parent id in the checksum. This is what makes git cyrptographically secure (it is easy to verify integrity of the whole repository from any snapshot down to the root commit).

To compare branches containing the same 'logical' commits, but rebased or cherry picked onto another, do e.g.

```
log --left-right --graph --oneline --cherry-pick BRANCH1 BRANCH2
```

As the manpage for git rev-list (among others) explains, `--cherry-pick` causes

> --cherry-pick
>
> ```
>     Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on
>     the "other side" when the set of commits are limited with symmetric
>     difference.
>
>     For example, if you have two branches, A and B, a usual way to list all
>     commits on only one side of them is with --left-right (see the example
>     below in the description of the --left-right option). It however shows
>     the commits that were cherry-picked from the other branch (for example,
>     "3rd on b" may be cherry-picked from branch A).
>
>     With this option, such pairs of commits are excluded from the output.
> ```